# C# - How to get datagridvier column header name

Tags: datagridview

I have a Windows Form application with DataGridView control which has two header columns (naming "Phone", "Choice").

I want to use header name to set the new column component name.

For example: The column header text is "Choice" and name is "ckbChoice".

I want to adds new rows by for loop 0 to 10, naming "ckbChoice_0"...."ckbChoice_1"...etc

So i need to get the column header name, the "ckbChoice" of CheckBox name.

How can i get the column header name?

I have try this, but doesn't work.

```
DataGridViewCell CellHeader = DataGridView1[1, -1]; // RowIndex is -1.

string HeaderName = CellTemp.OwningColumn.Name; // Get column header name
```

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
   String HeaderName=DataGridView1.column[Columnindex].HeaderText ;
```